# Vue 3 / Pinia: how to get the updated value from the store when it's changed?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

Using Vue 3 with Pinia in an Interia setup. I can see Pinia in my Dev Tools and I can console log out the (starting) value.

I have a component set up like:

```
<Comment>
    <ChildComment>
```

In ChildComment, I have this function

```
const toggleEdit = () => {
    commentStore.childEditing = !editMode.value

    editMode.value = !editMode.value;
};
```

When I trigger this function, the value updates in the store:

[image: store screenshot]

In the `<Comment>` component, I have tried using various methods like so:

```
import { useStore } from "../../store/commentStore";
const commentStore = useStore();


// USING STATE DIRECTLY
// const isEditingChildComment = ref(commentStore.childEditing);
// const isEditingChildComment = reactive(commentStore.childEditing);
// const isEditingChildComment = computed(() => commentStore.childEditing);

// USING GETTER
// const isEditingChildComment = ref(commentStore.getChildEditing);
// const isEditingChildComment = reactive(commentStore.getChildEditing);
// const isEditingChildComment = computed(() => commentStore.getChildEditing);
```

But `isEditingChildComment` is never updated in any of the above 6 scenarios, it remains as false:

[image: Component stuff]

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: What is getChildEditing? You shouldn't mutate `commentStore.childEditing` outside the store. The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It's unknown what went wrong, and where

Comment: I have a photo of the store showing that getChildEditing is a getter, and reference that in the "// USING GETTER" bit of my comments. It's a getter in the Pinia store.

Comment: But you didn't show how exactly it's implemented. The problem is that you describe the problem that shouldn't exist in the first place. Considering that there are no underlying problems, this `computed(() => commentStore.childEditing)` should work, as well as using `commentStore.getChildEditing` directly. Please, provide a way to reproduce the problem. The question doesn't contain enough information.

Answer (score 2):

If you use [a computed property](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#computed-properties), you need to return a value. For example:

```
const isEditingChildComment = computed(() => {
   return commentStore.childEditing);
}
```

It looks also if you are mutating the store state directly. I think you [should use an Action](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/actions.html) for that, to guarantee the working of reactivity.

Comment: Isn't this implicit return though? `computed(() => commentStore.childEditing)` You don't require the return key word in a fat arrow like this?

Comment: Well, VS code/ ESlint is always complaining if I do not return a value. I get the warning: **Expected to return a value in computed function.**

Comment: But isn't there a way just to get the $%^&* value from the store without all this pretzel logic? Shouldn't it just be able to be referenced in a component as commentStore.childEditing?

Comment: @MaxRocket I think you can do that with Pinia. In the docs they show an example direct state mutation: https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/state.html#accessing-the-state